# How to add submit button to form code without any javascript or jquery?

Tags: html, forms, button, hyperlink

I want to add submit button to following code, so after submitting button forwards to other url.

```
    
        Réglementation internationale 15
        Réglementation 15
```

Comment: where is your code???

Comment: This the code <form >
    <select name="forma" onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value="http://test.com/fr/reglementation-internationale/">Réglementation internationale 15</option>
        <option value="http://test.com/fr/reglementation-union-europeenne/">Réglementation 15</option>
    </select>
</form>